# Blender 2.8 procedural texture defaulting to pink

Tags: texturing, procedural

I am attempting to create a procedural texture to generate land masses, oceans, and clouds on a "planet." I used a series of voronoi and noise textures to generate this image.
[image: Planet Image without clouds]

When I attempt to add clouds to this texture with a darken and add node (Remove color from area where clouds will be, then add the clouds into the now black areas), the final image becomes pink (the missing texture default color).

[image]

When I remove the land texture, or the ocean texture, the clouds are correctly added, and the ocean and land textures work together, but when I use all three I run into the error. Here is the complete node setup (Causes error).
[image]

While these setups do not cause any errors.

[image]
[image]

Here is the link to the file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/msvw8v99efdr8c9/Planet_2.blend?dl=0

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your shader tree might be using all the allocated texture memory of your graphics card. did you try rendering using cycles?

Comment: I just tried rending with cycles and it worked. Would you happen to know of a way to get around the graphics card limitation? Could I use the hard drive memory when the graphics card is full?

Comment: It seems to be a limitation of eevee and your GPU, hard disk memory and RAM are not used in processing shaders as far as I know. So you would have to go back to the tree and optimize it for eevee

Comment: Yea, I think that's what I'll do. Thanks for the help :)